# Pandas: How to filter by month and year and return max value by grouped id?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following tasks to perform on the DataFrame:

1. Filter date by September 2014 and store in a new DataFrame.
2. Find revenue generated by each shop.
3. Find max revenue generated in the month of September 2014.

I tried this python 3 code.

```
def get_year(x):
    return x.split(".")[-1]

def get_month(x):
    return x.split(".")[-2]


transactions['year'] = transactions['date'].map(get_year)
transactions['month'] = transactions['date'].map(get_month)

transactions['item_cnt_day'] = transactions['item_cnt_day'].replace(-1.0, 0)

transactions["Revenue"] = transactions["item_price"]*transactions["item_cnt_day"]

sort = transactions[(transactions["year"] == 2014) & (transactions["month"] == 9)]

max(sort.groupby(transactions["Revenue"]).sum())

date date_block_num shop_id item_id item_price item_cnt_day year month  Revenue
02.01.2013     0      59    22154   999.00     1.0          2013    01  999.00
03.01.2013     0      25    2552    899.00     1.0          2013    01  899.00
05.01.2013     0      25    2552    899.00     0.0          2013    01  0.00
06.01.2013     0      25    2554    1709.05    1.0          2013    01  1709.05
15.01.2013     0      25    2555    1099.00    1.0          2013    01  1099.00
```

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for pointing that out. I have removed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#changed sample data for Septmber 2014
print (transactions)
         date  date_block_num  shop_id  item_id  item_price  item_cnt_day
0  02.01.2013               0       59    22154      999.00           1.0
1  03.01.2013               0       25     2552      899.00           1.0
2  05.09.2014               0       25     2552      899.00           0.0
3  06.09.2014               0       25     2554     1709.05           1.0
4  15.09.2014               0       26     2555     1099.00           1.0
```

First convert column `date` to datetimes and extract year and month:

```
transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['date'], dayfirst=True)
transactions['year'] = transactions['date'].dt.year
transactions['month'] = transactions['date'].dt.month

transactions['item_cnt_day'] = transactions['item_cnt_day'].replace(-1.0, 0)
transactions["Revenue"] = transactions["item_price"]*transactions["item_cnt_day"]
print (transactions)
        date  date_block_num  shop_id  item_id  item_price  item_cnt_day  \
0 2013-01-02               0       59    22154      999.00           1.0   
1 2013-01-03               0       25     2552      899.00           1.0   
2 2014-09-05               0       25     2552      899.00           0.0   
3 2014-09-06               0       25     2554     1709.05           1.0   
4 2014-09-15               0       26     2555     1099.00           1.0   

   year  month  Revenue  
0  2013      1   999.00  
1  2013      1   899.00  
2  2014      9     0.00  
3  2014      9  1709.05  
4  2014      9  1099.00  

sort = transactions[(transactions["year"] == 2014) & (transactions["month"] == 9)]
print (sort)
        date  date_block_num  shop_id  item_id  item_price  item_cnt_day  \
2 2014-09-05               0       25     2552      899.00           0.0   
3 2014-09-06               0       25     2554     1709.05           1.0   
4 2014-09-15               0       26     2555     1099.00           1.0   

   year  month  Revenue  
2  2014      9     0.00  
3  2014      9  1709.05  
4  2014      9  1099.00
```

Aggregate `sum` by column `shop_id`:

```
out1 = sort.groupby('shop_id', as_index=False)['Revenue'].sum()
print (out1)
   shop_id  Revenue
0       25  1709.05
1       26  1099.00
```

Get shop by maximal value of `Revenue` in `out1`:

```
out2 = out1.set_index('shop_id')['Revenue'].idxmax()
print (out2)
25
```

Comment: i get revenue like this:  1.228824e+06                                       this is what i got for printing out1. i followed the same steps as mentioned above

Comment: @VinitSutar - it means there are large data, some `e` is used. It is problem?

Comment: I dont know if thats a problem or not, but i think this is calculating maximum revenue of all the shops. but i want to know maximum revenue amongst all. This code is adding the revenue of all shops. I want an individual revenue of a shop which had the top revenue. How shall i approach this problem?

Comment: @VinitSutar - So need `out2 = sort.groupby('shop_id', as_index=False)['Revenue'].max()`, right?

Comment: yes, out2 should have the revenue of that one shop which topped it all

Comment: @VinitSutar - Check edit, need [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)

Comment: Sorry its not out2, its out1. My bad, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: can you tell me what out1 is doing? is out1 adding the revenue of each shop?? because idxmax will give which shop earned the top revenue, i want to know the highest revenue of the shop which topped it.

Comment: @VinitSutar - it is DataFrame by aggregate `sum`, do you need something else? If yes, can you explain more?

Comment: Okay out1 is adding the total revenue of each shop correct?

Comment: @VinitSutar - exactly.

Comment: and later out2 which you calculated previously, it was giving maximum revenue for the month of sep 2014 amongst the 'n' shops , right??

Comment: @VinitSutar - out2 is counter from out1 - but if need count from sort, use `out2 = sort.set_index('shop_id')['Revenue'].idxmax()` - then it count from each row of sort filtered data

Comment: max_revenue = out1.set_index('shop_id')['Revenue'].max()    i think this will give me max revenue of the shop which made highest revenue in sep 2014, am i correct?